# Change logo bassed on language in opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to make the main logo of the store change when I change language.
My company has a different name in English (originally in Hebrew).

Comment: There is no question in the 'question'...

Comment: @Paebbels how load pic based on language that i mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using OC 2.X then you can get the Language code in header.tpl file like this

```
$session = new Session();
$lang = $session->data['language'];
echo $lang // out put will be 'en' for enlgish
```

Then you can place condition to change the image URL, also you can place condition in header controller so controller will send the appropriate logo URL in `$logo`  variable.

Comment: **thank you very much** its work like a charm, can u tell me where can found OC 2.X  developer guide , thank you

Comment: It's unnecessary to create a new instance of Session, because it's available anywhere through the OpenCart registry pattern. Just use $this->session->data['language'] anywhere in your MVC structure.

Comment: @ckonig As you wrote, it works with below version 2.0, if you are using V 2.0 then you have to create instance in template file then you can access it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I've always worked with 1.9.x. In that case i'd put the code in the controller, so the template doesn't need to know where the value comes from.

Comment: there are no version like 1.9, its last version before 2.0 was 1.5.6

Answer (score 1):

```
$lang = $this->language->get('code');
```

use this line of code to check your language and then use if else to set your logo.

Comment: If you concatenate the language code to the image name (e.g. "logo-EN.png") you don't have to change the code again when you add a new language.